# Problema ao realizar XHR no mesmo domínio (localhost)

Tags: php, javascript, html, cross-domain, xmlhttprequest

## Explicação:

Possuo uma aplicação rodando em um computador de um cliente, funcionou normalmente algum tempo, depois alguma coisa aconteceu que **o sistema só podia ser acessado de fora e localmente não funcionava mais**.

## Problema:

XHR não está conseguindo ser realizado e no firefox o firebug me retorna o seguinte erro:

> "Pedido entre origens bloqueado: a política de mesma origem proíbe a leitura de recursos remotos em `http://localhost:3581/datasnap/rest/TdssMloteamento/getLoteamento/true/`. Isto pode ser corrigido movendo-se o recurso para o mesmo domínio ou ativando o CORS."

O que é MUITO estranho, pois ao meu entendimento este erro poderia ocorrer caso acessado de um domínio diferente **"de fora"** e não ao contrário, que seria o caso do local host funcionando perfeitamente, e no localhost não funciona mais

Como resolver isto? o que realmente está acontecendo? porque a lógica de dar erro de origem diferente não se aplica desde que o sistema está rodando no cliente e o proprio cliente do proprio computador mesmo do servidor não consgue-acessa-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Não apenas o **domínio**, mas o **protocolo** (*ex: http vs https*) e a **porta** devem ser iguais. Para resolver este problema, é necessário adicionar no cabeçalho da requisição o parâmetro **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**. Em PHP, acredito que possa ser feito com algo do tipo:

```
<?php    
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
```

Comment: Esse php está autorizando qualquer origem, não? Se for, é bom deixar claro.

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema. Consegui resolver incluindo no arquivo php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```